# Haskell: Why is it a problem to re-assign the tail of a variable to its own variable?

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, freeze

Suppose you have a variable with the following list:

```
Prelude> arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

And you do,

```
Prelude> arr
[1,2,3,4,5]
Prelude> arr = tail arr
Prelude> arr
```

Why does the compiler freeze up now? I am trying to implement this code statement in a recursion, but this phenomenon is preventing my recursion from working properly – it keeps returning an empty list error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Haskell, a variable is always in scope in its own definition. What you probably intended was this

```
Prelude> arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
Prelude> arr1
[1,2,3,4,5]
Prelude> arr2 = tail arr1
Prelude> arr2
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But when you write `arr = tail arr`, the REPL forgets the previous definition of `arr` and defines a new one which is equal to *its own* tail. Then you do

```
Prelude> arr
```

Haskell comes along and evaluates that to `tail arr`, and [`tail`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/GHC-List.html#tail) evaluates its argument to [WHNF](https://wiki.haskell.org/Weak_head_normal_form), so to identify `tail arr`, we need to know the shape of `arr`, which is, of course, `tail arr`. So to know `arr`, we need to know `arr`. Hence, `arr` is [bottom](https://wiki.haskell.org/Bottom), a nonterminating value. The previous definition is irrelevant.

If you had tried to do this in a Haskell source file (as opposed to the command line interactive environment), you'd get a compiler error, as it's incorrect to rebind an existing name in the same scope. It's only a feature of the REPL that you're allowed to do so for testing purposes.

Comment: I'd remark that it _is_ possible to re-use variable names in GHCi, you just can't refer to the old values inside the new definition. But this works: `> let arr = [1..5]`; `arr`⇒[1,2,3,4,5]; `let arr = tail it`; `arr`⇒[2,3,4,5]

Comment: The repl doesn't really "forget" the previous definition. `let x = 3; let f = const x; let x = 4; print (f 'a')`. This will print `3`, not `4`. The earlier definition is just *shadowed*.